# Why does this code cause an Expected ")" error?

Tags: php, error-handling, iteration, syntax-error

```
<?php
  $i == array(1, 2); 
  $j == array(a, b); 
  $m == count($j); 
  $n == count($i); 
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $m; i++ ) 
  {
    for ( $j = 0; j < $n; j++) 
    { echo $i."x"$j; }
  }
?>
```

The error is referencing line 6: `for ( $i = 0; $i < $m; i++ )`

Comment: `{ echo $i."x"$j; }` syntax error here - there's no operator between the `"x"` and `$j`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for ( $i = 0; $i < $m; $i++ )`

Note the dollar sign I added before the `i++`

Same goes for your other `for` statement:

`for ( $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++ )`

Wierd error indeed, but it `i` is not a variable (although PHP might flag a `E_NOTICE` and convert it to `'i'`.  You want to reference your variable, so you must add a `$` before.

---

Most likely what you want is:

```
<?php
  $iArray = array(1, 2); 
  $jArray = array('a', 'b'); 
  $n = count($iArray); 
  $m = count($jArray); 
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    for ( $j = 0; $j < $m; $j++) { 
       echo $iArray[$i] . "x" . $jArray[$j]; 
    }
  }
?>
```

The things I changed:

- `==` is used for comparison, `=` is used for assignment
- The second array I assumed you wanted the string literals `'a'` and `'b'`, but you could have also wanted `$a` and `$b` if you declared those variables somewhere else
- you assign `$i` to an array, but then in your for loop you overwrite it with `$i = 0`.  You most likely want two variables
- missing `$`s, like I mentioned above
- `$m` was being used for the number of variables in `$jArray`, but you used it to iterate over `$iArray`

---

So just a few pointers, brush up on you [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) and try to make sure your code works with every little change.  Make 1 modification, then run it.  It is very easy to get lost in syntax for PHP since it is such a dynamic scripting language

Comment: I'd hardly call it 'weird', `i` would be a valid statement if a constant (and a notice if not), `i++` wouldn't, so it says "instead of `++` I expected `)`".

Comment: Some people here were telling me that, also.  I kept looking at it and actually seeing the $ sign.  Isn't that strange?  The more I looked at it, the more it seemed like a dollar sign was there.  Then all of the sudden, it hit me.  There wasn't any dollar sign!

Comment: Anyway, the issues I noticed, thanks to you, were: using too few variables, not putting $ before a variable, incorrect use of equality operator, and not putting quotes around my string literals.  The T_INC error was thrown due to the missing $'s.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bunch of equality checks there. I'm assuming you were actually assigning variables rather than checking for equality.

Change all == equality checks to assignments (=)

Answer (score 1):

You also have improper concatenation on line 9 and I added a comment pointing out another possible error.

```
$i == array(1, 2); 
$j == array($a, $b); // <--Put in $ signs if these are variables in the array
$m == count($j); 
$n == count($i); 
for ( $i = 0; $i < $m; $i++ ) 
{
  for ( $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) 
  { echo $i."x".$j; }
}
```

Comment: Oh you mean the missing .?  I picked that up at the very last.  How cool, you noticed it first. :)